# how to format custom cell in excel to show only time in minutes an seconds

Tags: excel, calculated-field

how to format custom cell to show only time in minuets an seconds only in excel; every time i change to custom time format it should be entered hh:mm:ss while my imported data is only `mm:ss` but it show as `hh:mm:ss` let’s say it show as `17:36:00` how to change it to `00:17:36` ? and for better result I need it to be show in minuets and seconds only `17:36` and to be calculated field normally as `00:17:36`

Using the custom time `mm:ss` show my result `36:00` which is not true

Comment: Divide the cell by 60

Comment: maybe I should use this method .. i hoped ther is a direct one. Thank you

Comment: In addition to dividing by 60, you should customformat the cell as `[mm]:ss`

Comment: The other option is to edit the cover outside of excel and add the 00: to the front of the times. This needs to be done before opening and saving in excel.

Answer (score 0):

So no problem: use custom format as mm:ss like so:

[image]
Does exactly what you ask, shows the time as minutes and second but the cell has hours so calculation as hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: it doesnt work, your solution valid only if the imported data showed be into hh:mm:ss but this is not my case .. the imported data in minutes and seconds only.

Comment: Works for me - that is copied off the sheet.

Comment: My imported data was in CSV, all I need to convert 17:36:00 into 00:17:36 .. like shiting the hh filed to the mm filed and not to convert it into minutes "1056" in your solution I got 36:00 and it is not what I want.